# Ubuntu Linux Proxy Server for a network of Windows 10 and imac pcs i

Tags: networking, proxy

Waht is the feasibility of running an ubuntu proxy server on a lan in order to better implement family parental controls on a network of windows 10 and imac pcs?

Ie will an ubuntu server be a suitable solution for this on an exclusively windows and imac home network?

My thoughts are to:

- use Linux as the basis
- be able to selectively add restrictions via device or even better, user level controls (therefore users on any device can have personalised restrictions...meaning my wife doesnt have to contact me to allow her access to one of the kids devices outside the preset time restrictions on a particular device)

What are the pros and cons of doing this?

Comment: Probably "Yes". What do you mean by "Parental controls"?

Comment: Sorry i edited my question so it makes more sense. I wish to run an internet gateway via a proxy with the aim of adding better controls for device/user account time limits and URL restrictions.